# Response.cookie is not defined

Tags: typescript, nestjs, backend

I'm quite new in [NestJS](https://nestjs.com/) and I'm using it to handle a rest API server. I'm trying to send some HTTP-only cookie in the response and I'm following the [official documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/cookies#use-with-express-default) and it suggests to use the `cookie` method in the `Response` object but it looks like that method is not defined. This is my code:

```js
@Get('login')
verifyLoginEmailCode(
  @Headers() { email, password }: LoginInputDto,
  @Res({ passthrough: true }) res: Response,
) {
  // as per official documentation res.cookie should be a function but it's not defined
  console.log(Object.keys(res)); // in the keys "cookie" is missing

  return this.authAdminService.login(email, password);
}
```

Is there any mistake?

Comment: Type of res shouldn't be Response instead of ServerResponse as documentation noted? Do you import correctly?

Comment: Thanks for the response @MohammadHosseinDolatabadi, that was a typo when I was writing my code in stackoverflow, it is correct on my original code. I'm going to fix my question.

Comment: Do you import essentials correctly? you should import Response from express and Req from @nestjs/common.

Comment: Thanks @MohammadHosseinDolatabadi that was the issue I was importing both from `@nestjs/common`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should import them correctly. you should import Response from express and `Req` from `@nestjs/common`.